# How to using the Markov Inequality to find the upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(X > 2)$ given I only have information about $X^4$?

Tags: probability-inequalities, bounds

Let  $X$  be a nonnegative random variable that satisfies  $\mathbb{E}[X^{4}]=4$ .

---

**How should I calculate an estimate for the $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 2)$ using the Markov Inequality?**

---

I tried to find a relation between $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^{4}]$, but couldn't find a generalization.

I wondered if I could assume that $\mathbb{E}[X^{4}] = (\mathbb{E}[X])^{\frac{1}{4}}=4$ so I tried some simple modeling using R.

Here's my code.

```
sample = 1000000 
set.seed(3535) 
z = rexp(n = sorteio, rate = 2) #Z is nonnegative.

mean(z)
#> [1] 0.5008756 
mean(z^0.25)
#> [1] 0.7625577 
(mean(z))^0.25
#> [1] 0.8412643
```

As I suspected, I cannot make that generalization.

Can someone point in the right direction?

Comment: Hint: Jensen's Inequality will give you a relationship between $\mathbb{E}X$ and $\mathbb{E}X^4$.   Another, more useful, hint:  define $Y  = X^4$.  Now you have $\mathbb{E}Y = 4$.  If $X>2$, can you make any statement about $Y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the proof of Markov's Inequality for nonnegative random variables $Y$. It is based on the observation that for $y > 0$, $~\alpha^{-1} y > \mathbb 1_{y > \alpha}$ and so
$$E[\alpha^{-1} Y] \geq E[\mathbb 1_{Y > \alpha}] = P\{Y > \alpha\}$$
or equivalently,
$$P\{Y > \alpha\} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}E[Y].$$
Then observe that $\left(\frac x2\right)^4 > \mathbb 1_{x > 2}$ and so it must be that
$$E\left[\left(\frac X2\right)^4\right] = \frac 14 \geq E[\mathbb 1_{X > 2}] = P\{X >2\}.$$